# How to map a JavaScript iterable without writing an iteration function?

Tags: javascript, iterable

Some methods in Javascript, for example `Map.prototype.values`, return an iterable.  Without writing a function to iterate through the values, can I map them to something else as per `Array.prototype.map`?  Is there a way to realize the iterable's values into an Array object that I can then invoke the `map` method of?

Or do I have to write something like

```js
function realize(it) {
  let result = Array();
  for (i of it) {
    result.push(i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

every time I need to do this in js?

Comment: Realised before posting that this is what the ellipsis "spread" syntax does, but posted the question anyway because the answer wasn't readily found with my search terms.

Comment: There's also [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the goal is specifically to map your values to something else, you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a mapping callback.

```
Array.from(iterable, x => x * 2);
```

This prevents having to construct an intermediate array, and having to iterate twice over the values. In terms of both space and time complexity, `Array.from()` handily beats the combination of [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: I guess the spread syntax has a small advantage in terms of code size (at least pre-minification), but I do like this solution better.

Comment: That's a really small advantage. `[...iterable].map(x => x * 2);` is 3 characters shorter :)

Comment: Sure, but if your code size is a critical factor and the code you're using this for doesn't execute frequently enough to be impactful on client resources, it might be worth saving a few characters here and there.

Comment: don't use `Array.from(any, fn)` it's very slow: https://jsbench.me/ltlfbviyw3/1

Comment: after about 20 test runs I always find `Array.from().map()` faster or equal

Comment: @TachibanaShin It's not inherently slow. I've tried your benchmark on both Chrome and Firefox, and the results are always within a 5% range, sometimes one being slower, sometimes the other.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen maybe it has more to do with processor speed. on my 14nm and 8-core 2.1Mhz it's significantly slower

Comment: maybe we should consider this when in a looper like `requestAnimatonFrame`

Comment: Array.from is slow. That's because it doesn't allocate space for the array first even if the length of the new array is known in advance and because it inserts undefined into the array where previously there was an empty slot. Therefore it has to allocate space for a new array every time it fills up which is O(log n) memory allocations instead of O(1). So if the length of the new array is large and it is known in advance you're better off instantiating the new array with Array(length) then iterating over the iterable yourself and populating the new array that way. Just use a for loop it's easy

Comment: @PHPGuru What you are saying seems to directly contradict the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.from). Step 8 and step 10 clearly specify that if the iterable is array-like, the new array should be constructed with the length of the iterable. Will a standard `for` loop be faster? Probably. But that goes for pretty much every function defined on the array prototype.

Comment: @Robby My comment was about using Array.from with iterables. Array.from takes different steps when the input is an iterable than when it is a non-iterable array-like. Step 5 of the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.from) shows that it creates an array with length 0. And since most array-likes are iterables including arrays this applies most of the time. But your comment was still useful because it does point out that when used with non-iterable array-likes it does apparently allocate an array with a predetermined length. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's `...` [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can be used to realize an iterable.  E.G.

```js
[...iterable]
```

would do the same thing as `realize(iterable)` given the function defined in the question.

Comment: use `Array.from()` because it's 3-6 times faster

Comment: also if your goal is only value manipulation you can proceed to inherit prototype

Comment: @TachibanaShin What is the basis?

Comment: @Cognia a v8 test shows that. also we can explain that `spread dot` actually needs to read all the `props' like `for .. in` and `arrayfrom()` only cares about `.length` and it takes any property count from `0 -> length` even if it doesn't exist. `foo in { foo: undefined }` is true and `foo in {}` is false but `{}['foo']` is always undefined

Comment: Your explanation is awesome,thank you.